# Обособление оборота перед определяемым

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, причастный-оборот, авторская-пунктуация

Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужна ли запятая в этой конструкции на месте (?): "и прочие, уже упомянутые выше(?) проблемы".

Спасибо!